# Usage of typedef on function

Tags: c, function, typedef

What is the difference between the following function `typedef`:

```
typedef void tbl_opt (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);     // 1
typedef void *tbl_opt (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);    // 2
typedef void (*tbl_opt) (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);  // 3
typedef (void *) (*tbl_opt) (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param); // 4
```

Usually, I use the 3rd & 4th, but I saw the other 2 in a book, which I don't understand well.

---

[Update] **Summary:**

It seems when define type in case 1 or 2, when use that type, still need declare a pointer variable, and initialize it to point to another actual function, so I guess that's why case 3 & 4 are more popular.

Comment: @SLaks When I input `typedef int (*tbl_opt) (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);` , it told me `syntax error`. It's seems not that powerful.

Comment: What do you mean ? Please elaborate ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ashokv I saw the first 2 for the first time, but never see any use case of them before, so I was trying to understand when to use which?

Comment: @EricWang: Remove the parameter names and try again.

Comment: @SLaks When I input `typedef int (*tbl_opt) (void *, void *);` same result `syntax error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 and 4 are Function Pointers:

1. A Function that returns void or nothing and takes two void* arguments

   ```
   typedef void tbl_opt (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);
   ```
2. A function that returns a void* and takes two void * arguments

   ```
   typedef void *tbl_opt (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);
   ```
3. A function pointer to a function that returns void or nothing and takes two void* arguments

   ```
   typedef void (*tbl_opt) (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);
   ```
4. A Function pointer to a function that returns void* and takes two void* arguments

   ```
   typedef (void *) (*tbl_opt) (void *tbl_item, void *tbl_param);
   ```

Comment: I usually define a function pointer with typedef, can u give a use case of the 1st definition.

Comment: @EricWang `tbl_opt` is a function type, `tbl_opt *` is a function pointer. So you can write `tbl_opt *` wherever you're used to writing a function pointer typedef names.   You can also use `tbl_opt` to declare functions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ok, I see that now, I just wrote a program that use case 1. It seems should declare a pointer variable when use it.

Answer (score 4):

typedef to:

1. a function getting void pointers and returning void
2. a function getting void pointers and returning void **pointer**
3. a **pointer** to a function getting void pointers and returning void
4. a **pointer** to a function getting void pointers and returning void **pointer**

by the way, please read [Reading C Type Declarations](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) - it will change your life.