# Why is this usage of typedef-ed function an error?

Tags: c, function, typedef, c99

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*myfunc_t)(int x);

myfunc_t myfunc(int x)
{
    printf("x = %d\n", x);

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    myfunc_t pfunc = myfunc;

    (pfunc)(1);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling for C99, standard C, I get an error:

```
prog.c: In function ‘myfunc’:
prog.c:9:6: error: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void [-Werror]
      return;
      ^~~~~~
prog.c:5:14: note: declared here
     myfunc_t myfunc(int x)
              ^~~~~~
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:14:26: error: initialization of ‘myfunc_t’ {aka ‘void (*)(int)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘void (* (*)(int))(int)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
         myfunc_t pfunc = myfunc;
                          ^~~~~~
```

A few questions in SO already explain that the return type of `myfunc_t` is `void` (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30657500/274579)). So, why do I get these errors?

Note that if I change the type of `myfunc` from `myfunc_t` to `void`, then the program builds OK.

Comment: I don't understand what *you* don't understand. You function claims it returns a `myfunc_t`, but doesn't, It is then used in a context that expects a function returning `void`, which yours doesn't by declaration (forget about practice, which we already discussed). Changing to `void` fulfills *both* problems.

Comment: `myfunc_t` is an alias for a prototype, isn't it? A type of a function, that is, that returns a `void`. I am using this prototype to define a function that returns a `void`. I am surely missing something here, but I still expect this to work.

Comment: It's a pointer-to-function *type* alias. Prototype has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, see my comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947063/274579 Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use typedef to *define* a function, but you can use a typedef of a function type to *declare one*. If you've got a function *pointer* type like in the question then that can be used to *neither* declare *nor* define a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myfunc_t myfunc(int x)
```

This statement creates a function `myfunc` which returns a function pointer `myfunc_t`

But in the function definition you are not returning anything. Also what this does is make `myfunc` incompatible with the `myfunc_t` type (return values are different)

What you need is to declare and define the function as

```
void myfunc(int x) 
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: I think I got my conceptual error. Contrary to what I wrote in the comment to the question, this is not rally a prototype. The definition of the function `myfunc` should have returned an object similar to `pfunc` in order to be correct.